# How to add extra cells in a UITableView in editing mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Do you know how to have some cells appear in a table view after the table goes into editing mode? Just like the "Contacts" iPhone app does when you edit a contact.

Maybe I'm wrong, but when editing the contacts, it looks like a grouped UITableView is used.

I tried this:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

My table has only 1 section when not editing it, I wanted to add an extra section when editing (to keep it simple), but the call to 'insertSections' above crashes (all my table delegates take into account the 1 or 2 sections well depending on self.editing, I tried showing both sections in normal mode, and it works fine)

For 'numberOfSectionsInTableView' I have:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!self.editing) return 1;
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did you enter the editing state of the tableView? You should do it in -[UINavigationController setEditing:animated:]:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing){
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    } else {
        // delete section
    }
}
```

So instead of calling setEditing on the tableView, call it on the navigationController (probably `self`) The controller will then handle the editing mode.

So the controller has an editing mode, and the tableView has. The tableView will be in editing mode once you set it programmatically, or when the user swipes to delete a row. In the latter case, the *controller* is **not** in editing mode, but the *tableView* **is**.

Comment: Excellent! Indeed, the problem was a confusion with what was in editing mode. Thanks much!

Comment: Do I have to subclass UINavigationController or where do I put your proposed Code? Thank you

Comment: The code shown here is used in a subclass of `UITableViewController`, which may be a child controller of a `UINavigationController`. The `UINavigationController` handles displaying the navigation bar and current view (controller), you don't need a subclass for that. The `UITableViewController` however handles all information of a tableview, so you do need a subclass of that class.